# Как запретить доступ по IP ко всем php файлам, кроме index.php?

Tags: .htaccess

Сейчас в .htaccess есть такой код, который разрешает открывать только index.php.

```
<Files *.php> 
  deny from all 
</Files>
<Files index.php> 
  allow from all 
</Files>
```

Но как сделать, чтобы index.php могли смотреть все, а остальные файлы только по определенному IP адресу?

Comment: Это плохая идея. Если с вашим IP что-то случиться, вы потеряете доступ к управлению сайтом. Кроме того, это очень похоже на попытку заняться отладкой на проде, что тоже является гнусной практикой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы разрешать или запрещать доступ, анализируя IP-адрес клиента, можно указывать адрес или подсеть в директиве from. Кроме того необходимо указать, что по умолчанию выполняется запрет или разрешение для остальных адресов:

```
<Files *.php> 
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 10.39.9.85
</Files>
<Files index.php> 
  Allow from all 
</Files>
```

Возможно, вам потребуется получить возможность указания директив доступа в файлах .htaccess для определённой директории, используемой apache для определённого сайта, иначе указанные директивы могут быть проигнорированы.

Для этого найдите в конфигурационном файле apache (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf, /etc/httpd/httpd.conf) и укажите какие свойства вы хотели бы переопределять в .htaccess (для простоты можно указать, что разрешается изменять любые свойства - AllowOverride All):

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Подробности по Allow / Deny в .htaccess:
https://htaccessbook.com/block-ip-address/

Подробности по AllowOverride в конфигурации директории:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride